# How to combine multiple count statements in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count, sum

I have a table with a list of ID's and each ID has a Status of either HW, HB, PIP or TBC.

I want to count the number of people with each of these statuses, so I would have a table looking like

HW  HB  PIP  TBC

45  27  9    49

At the minute I have

```
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'StatusHW' From HomeworkerStatus WHERE Status='Homeworker')
    UNION       
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'StatusHB' From HomeworkerStatus WHERE Status='Home Based')
    UNION
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'StatusPIP' From HomeworkerStatus WHERE Status='PIP') 
    UNION
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'StatusTBC' From HomeworkerStatus WHERE Status='TBC')
```

This returns

StatusHW

1  45

2  27

3  9

4  49

I have also tried

```
    SELECT Status,
    sum(case when Status = 'Homeworker' then 1 else 0 end) StatusHW,
    sum(case when Status = 'Home Based' then 1 else 0 end) StatusHB,
    sum(case when Status = 'PIP' then 1 else 0 end) StatusPIP,
    sum(case when Status = 'TBC' then 1 else 0 end) StatusTBC
    FROM HomeworkerStatus
    GROUP BY Status
```

This retunrs a 4x4 table with rows 1,2,3,4 and columns Status,StatusHW,...,StatusTBC. This is closer to what I am after, but still not right.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just remove `group by` as have already dealt with those conditions while aggregating as:

```
 SELECT 
    -- Status,
    sum(case when Status = 'Homeworker' then 1 else 0 end) StatusHW,
    sum(case when Status = 'Home Based' then 1 else 0 end) StatusHB,
    sum(case when Status = 'PIP' then 1 else 0 end) StatusPIP,
    sum(case when Status = 'TBC' then 1 else 0 end) StatusTBC
    FROM HomeworkerStatus
    -- GROUP BY Status
```

Comment: Works like a dream, Thanks!

Comment: In what way is this different from @ThorstenKettner's answer?

Comment: Well while answering he missed to remove Status column and in that case aggregation won't work as with no group by we can't have non-aggregate columns in select clause. Hope it clarifies the point.

Answer (score 5):

Don't `GROUP BY Status`, if you want only one line:

```
SELECT
sum(case when Status = 'Homeworker' then 1 else 0 end) StatusHW,
sum(case when Status = 'Home Based' then 1 else 0 end) StatusHB,
sum(case when Status = 'PIP' then 1 else 0 end) StatusPIP,
sum(case when Status = 'TBC' then 1 else 0 end) StatusTBC
FROM HomeworkerStatus;
```

Comment: I had done this initially, but get the error
'Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'HomeworkerStatus.Status' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.'

Comment: You need to remove the `SELECT Status`. Othervise the query will not run

Comment: @Arion: Right, I overlooked that. Thanks; I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Ahh yes, just realised that. Thanks!

Comment: @ThorstenKettner : Now you got a +1